# Efficient element-wise multiplication of a matrix and a matrix in Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

What would be the most efficient way to multiply:
Matrix A(shape: 4m * n, shape of A1: m * n)

```
A1
A2
A3
A4
```

by a matrix(shape: 4m * n, shape of B1: m * n):

```
B1
B2
B3
B4
```

to obtain a new matrix(shape: 4m * m):

```
A1B1
A2B2
A3B3
A4B4
```

Comment: A*B should be pretty fast

Comment: the shape of A * B is 4m*n not 4m*m

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I am interpreting your question as follows :
You have matrices `A1, A2, A3, A4` and `B1, B2, B3, B4`, all of which have sizes `m x n`. You want to form a `4m x n` matrix which is formed by element-wise multiplication of the corresponding matrices, stacked together in the first dimension. Here is how you can do it :

```
tf.concat_v2([A1*B1, A2*B2, A3*B3, A4*B4], 0)
```